# SQL Server: Data Page size confusion: 8060 + 96 byte is still less than 8k byte

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server stores data in **pages of 8k (8192) bytes**. In a data page, 96 bytes are reserved for page header. Considering the maximum allowed capacity of 8060 bytes for a data page, there are still 36 bytes remained. But I couldn't find any reference talking where this 36-byte block goes to.

Any help?

Comment: See [Paul Randal's excellent post on the topic](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/) - besides the 96 byte header on the page, each page also needs space for the *slot array* at the end of the page taking up some space. Or [see this SImple-Talk post on the page internals](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-storage-internals-101/)

Comment: @marc_s If the remaining 32 bytes goes to slot array then each page cannot contains more than 16 rows since each element of the array occupies 2 bytes that is not a correct assumption. Moreover, in SimpleTalk [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-storage-internals-101/) there is a picture depicted the anatomy of a page which clearly states body includes slot array.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15053/3690

Answer (score 3):

There is no fixed size specified for Slot Array/Row Offset Array.

Page header occupies the first 96 bytes of each data page (**leaving 8,096 bytes for data, row overhead, and row offsets**). Out of this, the maximum size of a single data row can be 8,060 bytes.

The number of rows stored on a given page varies depending on the table
structure and on the data being stored. A table with all fixed-length columns always can store the same number of rows per page; variable-length rows can store as many rows as will fit based on the actual length of the data entered.

For example, a page can contain more than 19 rows where each row size is 403 bytes. In this case, slot array size would be 38 bytes.